# Replacing IC with similar yet not sure

Tags: microcontroller

i have a coding machine here and on its pcb it has this IC ULN2003AN. it was burnt because of feedback polarity issue and i want to replace it with ULN2003APG. Is this possible, will it result to another problem. pls help.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Can you boil it down to a question at the end?

Comment: Also make sure you insert it the right way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the package is the same (14-pin DIP?) then there is little chance of a problem with the substitution.

However, if the original fault remains, then it will burn the replacement chip, also.

Comment: the fault is detachable, this is were the feedback alarm. anyways, are these two ICs compatible?

Comment: They are the same IC. The letters at the end are different because they may be different packages.

Comment: Thank you sir for your replies. May this one work as planned.